# Insertion in Mysql, where one column has a constant value

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with 2 column say C1 and C2. i need to insert 10 rows where always Columns 2 will be same.

```
INSERT INTO Table
 (C1, C2)
VALUES
  (100, 'X'),
  (101, 'X'),
  (102, 'X'),
  (103, 'X'),
  (104, 'X'),
  (105, 'X'),
  (106, 'X');
```

Is there any other way like below,

```
INSERT INTO Table
 (C1)
VALUES
  (100,102,103,104,105,106)
```

and value of C2 should be `X` for the inserted rows

Thanks in advance,

Comment: question makes no sense as it stands.

Comment: [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9db1f/2)

Comment: There a lot of possible ways ('DEFAULT' values, stored procedures, `INSERT ... SELECT`, etc). Can you give us more information about what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a table

```
CREATE TABLE `tblA` (
`C1` INT(10) NULL,
`C2` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'X'
);
```

Then when you do `INSERT INTO Table (C1) VALUES (100,102,103,104,105,106);` the column C2 will have 'X' as a value.

Answer (score 1):

There are, but not really very advantageous, one way or the other. If what you're trying to do is to write the constant value only once, I'd try to keep it simple and go for

```
SET @X := 'X'
```

or

```
SELECT @X := expression FROM ...
```

followed by

```
INSERT INTO Table
(C1, C2)
VALUES
(100, @X), (102, @X), ...;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply an insert into from a select statement  VALUES is hard-coded answers... insert into from select is query based insert.  In the sample below, I am using @MySQL variables to create a variable "@num" and start it at 99.  Then you just have to substitute per the sample as it describes... Any table that has at least the number of records you want to add.  So, in my case, I am only concerned with any table that has AT LEAST 10 records.  If you want to add 1000, and have a table with AT LEAST that many records, use that.  The LIMIT obviously limits how many records you return from it.  Since you are not really using any columns from the table, it doesn't matter what that table is.  So, now the @num := @num +1 will keep increasing for every record processed, thus going to 100, 101, 102, etc for the "c1" column, and the 'X' will be constanct for the "c2" column and you are done.

```
INSERT INTO Table
 (C1, C2)
select
      @num := @num +1 as c1,
      'X' as c2
   from
      AnyTableThatHasAtLeastNumberOfRecordsYouWant,
      ( select @num := 99 ) sqlvars
   limit
      10
```